# How do I use fsolve to solve a quadratic equation?

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

How do I use fsolve to calculate the value of y for the following non-linear equation in Python

`y=x^3 -√y`

(when x = 0, 1, 2.3611, 2.9033, 3.2859, 3.5915)

I have tried by solving the problem on paper and then using a function to calculate the value of y. But I am unable to use fsolve to do the same for me.

`def func(x):return np.round(((-1+np.sqrt(1+(4*x**3)))/2)**2,4)`

Comment: Please use appropriate markups to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

y = [0.000, 0.3820, 10.00, 20.00, 30.00, 40.00]

def func(x):
    for i in y:
        return x**3-(math.sqrt(i))

x0 = fsolve(func, [0, 1, 2.3611, 2.9033, 3.2859, 3.5915])
```

OutPut:

```
[0.00000000e+000 2.24279573e-109 5.29546580e-109 6.51151078e-109 7.36960349e-109 8.05500243e-109]

It is scientific notation. If 1e-5 It means 1 × 10−5. In other words, 0.00001.
```

Convert scientific notation to decimals:

```
Now, x0 = [0.00000000e+000 2.24279573e-109 5.29546580e-109 6.51151078e-109 7.36960349e-109 8.05500243e-109]

for i in x0:
    data = float("{:.8f}".format(float(str(i))))
    print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for updating the solution but I cant get the desired results using this. The anwers are supposed to be  (Answers: y = 0.000, 0.3820, 10.00, 20.00, 30.00, 40.00)   But using this I get [0.00000000e+000 2.24279573e-109 5.29546580e-109 6.51151078e-109  7.36960349e-109 8.05500243e-109]

Comment: Note that the equation is `f(y)=y+y**0.5-x**3`. One could also first solve `g(z)=z**2+z-x**3` and then for non-negative `z` transform to `y=z**0.5`

Comment: can you tell me how to print the results?

Comment: @user3227604 It is scientific notation. If 1e-5 It means 1 × 10−5. In other words, 0.00001.

Answer (score 0):

One should avoid the root functions if applying a numerical algorithm, at zero arguments the root function is non-smooth. Thus use `y=z²`, hoping that the function `z^2+z` is convex enough that starting at `1.0` the root-finding iteration stays with positive values for `z`, and take the square root of the result,

```
y = [ fsolve(lambda z: z**2+z-x**3, 1.0)[0]**2 for x in [0, 1, 2.3611, 2.9033, 3.2859, 3.5915] ]
```

This gets the solutions

```
[0.0, 0.3819660112501052, 10.000316539128024, 20.000195919522547, 30.00100142437062, 40.00161656606038]
```

Comment: the answer must be (Answers: y = 0.000, 0.3820, 10.00, 20.00, 30.00, 40.00)

Comment: You are right, I should follow my own derivation, `y=z**2`.